# Sharepoint removing Javascript function calls

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to call a simple javascript function which hides or shows a particular div in Sharepoint. I have added the Script Editor web part with the function in there, but the anchor tags have the href removed whenever I save. Below is the code as I enter it.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function toggleDiv(divId) {
        $("#"+divId).toggle();
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:toggleDiv('answer1');">Show Answer 1</a>
```

After I save, Sharepoint tells me that certain elements deemed "unsafe" by sharepoint would be removed. When it reloads, it removes the href as shown below:

```
<a>Show Answer 1</a>
```

Any ideas how I could get this simple function to work?

Thanks,
Jordan

Comment: bind the event from inside the script tag instead of using inline JS. give it an id, name or some other smoking gun to feed to a jQuery selector, then `.click(toggleDiv)` will setup the rest.

Comment: Since this will be used for multiple divIds in a single page, would I need to copy the script for each answer to feed different parameters?

Comment: no, you just add more rules to the selector using a comma to separate them. ex: `$("#div1, .clickers, a[href*=menu]").click(toggleDiv)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple answer you can create a simple script like this (i notice you are using jQuery)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
     $('#' + $(this).data('answer')).toggle();
  });
 });
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<a data-answer="answer1">Show answer 1</a>
<a data-answer="answer2">Show answer 2</a>
...
<div id="answer1" style="display:none">Here answer 1</div>
<div id="answer2" style="display:none">Here answer 2</div>
```

**UPDATE**: Added the `ready function` so the script will be run only when the page load completely

Comment: For some reason, this is making the link text (Show Answer 1) unclickable even though it's wrapped in an anchor tag...

Comment: You can use a `DIV` instead `a` so will be `<div data-answer="answer1">Show answer 1</div>` or add the `HREF` to `a` so will be `<a href="#" data-answer="answer1">Show answer 1</a>`

Comment: Still not working. I'm looking in the debugger and clicking the link or the div will not do anything. Forgive my ignorance, but what is "data-answer"?

Comment: I dont know which `browser and OS` you are using but the script is correct and working here in both of version. The `data` attribute is a way to add custom dta that can be read easly by jQuery as the example, see here for more info: [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Comment: @1337Atreyu i edit the script adding the function `ready` and let me know if working now

Comment: That still isn't working. It works when I run it locally on my own PC, but when I put this in the sharepoint document, it doesn't work.